# SAS-SQL Non-Equi Join

Tags: sql, join, sas, operators

I have two tables. When I join them using a left join on on table where one key matches and the other key doesn't match I'm still receiving a left join, but where the two don't match I'm receiving duplicates.

```
data Onl;
input an ssn;
datalines;
1  1
2  1
3  1
4  2
5  2
6  2
10 6
11 7
12 8
;
run;

data Off;
input an ssn;
datalines;
1 1
2 1
4 2
5 2
7 3
8 4
9 5
;
run;

proc sql;
create table test as
select
        Onl.*
from
Onl
left join Off
on Onl.ssn = Off.ssn
and Onl.an ne Off.an
;
quit;
```

What's the SQL behavior for `ne` conditions? I would expect the final table to consist of `var ssn` where `var an` do not match.
An example of expected output would be:

```
an ssn
3  1
6  2
10 6
11 7
12 8
```

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicates".  If there are three observations from the RIGHT table that match to an observation from the LEFT then the observation will appear three times.  If you are just pulling variables form the LEFT table then DISTINCT keyword will eliminate the duplicates, including elimination of any duplicates in the original LEFT table.

Comment: If I do this join in SAS I receive two lines with values `3,1` and two lines with values `6,2`. Why are there two rows with these values when there was originally only 1 row in the table `Onl` and the table `Off` didn't contain these values at all? I know of workarounds. I've just never used a join with `ne` and am curious about the results

Comment: I don't know why you say those values don't exist. The first two rows both have SSN=1 and the value of AN is not 3 for either of them. So it is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. How left join works is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization. PS If you want to know what is wrong with your expectations, you need to give them.

Answer (score 1):

`proc sql` is correctly processing the query.  A `left join` returns all rows in the first table, regardless of whether or not there is a match in the second table.

If you want the non-matching rows, I would recommend `not exists`:

```
select Onl.*
from Onl
where not exists (select 1
                  from off
                  where Onl.ssn = Off.ssn and
                        Onl.an = Off.an
                 );
```

You *can* use `join` with a `where` condition to check for non-matches:

```
select Onl.*
from Onl left join
     Off
     on Onl.ssn = Off.ssn and Onl.an = Off.an
where off.ssn is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The NE operator is evaluated the same as any other operator.  So your query is saying you want to match observations where SSN is the same and AN is not the same.  So SSN=1 and AN=3 will match with two observations that have SSN=1 but do not have AN=3. So the one observation will be output twice since it matches two observations.  The LEFT JOIN means that even when there are no observations where SSN matches and AN does not match then that observation is also output.

Perhaps you just want to use the EXCEPT set operation?

```
select ssn,an from ONL
except 
select ssn,an form OFF
```